# Geometric genus as dimension of a variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory

Given a smooth complex algebraic variety $X$ of dimension $n$, Hodge number $h^{1,0}(X)$ (irregularity) is the dimension of Albanese variety $A(X)$ of $X,$ so in particular it is non-zero if and only if $A(X)$ is nonzero. Is there a natural variety assigned to $X$, which is of dimension $h^{n,0}$ (geometric genus $p_g(X)$), or at least a natural geometric object measuring whether $p_g$ is nonzero?

Comment: The "canonical model" of $X$ is the closest I can think of to what you ask for.

Comment: The natural generalization of Albanese variety in higher dimension is _intermediate Jacobian_. For example, in $\dim X=3$, such variety has dimension $h^{3,0}+h^{2,1}$. It's not in general an algebraic torus, but when $X$ is Fano it is algebraic.